# How to set primefaces selectCheckboxMenu validator for minimum selects

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to write a validator for `primefaces` `selectCheckboxMenu` to prevent user from **selecting less than 5 values.**

I've tried to implement BalusC [RequiredCheckboxValidator](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/09/validate-required-checkbox.html#RequiredCheckboxValidator) but couldn't know how to access the size of selected values, can someone put me on the right path?

Comment: I haven't tried this by myself, but I guess you can access to the internal of the components using `UIComponent component` parameter in `validate` method and access to specific details of the component that is being validated, which would be, in this case, your `selectCheckboxMenu`.

Comment: great idea i will see what can i bring out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would do it in this way.

***xhtml***

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{mainBean.selectedList}" >  
    <f:selectItems value="#{mainBean.map}" />  
    <f:validator validatorId="limitCheckboxMenuValidator" />                       
    <f:attribute name="minLimit" value="5" />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

***Validator***

```
@FacesValidator("limitCheckboxMenuValidator")
public class LimitCheckboxMenuValidator implements Validator {

   public LimitCheckboxMenuValidator() {

   }

   @Override
   public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
           Object value) throws ValidatorException { 
       //get limit
       Integer minLimit =    Integer.parseInt((String)component.getAttributes().get("minLimit"));
       SelectCheckboxMenu myComponent = (SelectCheckboxMenu)component;

       if (((String[])myComponent.getSubmittedValue()).length < minLimit) {
           FacesMessage msg
                   = new FacesMessage("Limit failed",
                           "Min selection must be " + minLimit);
           msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
           throw new ValidatorException(msg);
       } 
   }
}
```

A small working example can be found on github [[1](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/selectCheckboxMenu/main.xhtml)] [[2](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ha/dailylab/LimitCheckboxMenuValidator.java)], and an [online Demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/selectCheckboxMenu/main.xhtml).

Hope this helps.